# Javascript variable in querystring not giving value just variable name

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a grid that I am passing the selected ID to a javascript function in an external file. When I step through the function I see the ID. This is the script that I am using to get the selected ID from the grid..

```
var myID;
// Get selected ID from radgrid 
function RowClick(sender, args) {
    var key = args.getDataKeyValue("EmployeeID");
    myID = key;
}
```

So I get the ID and I pass it to a variable so I can call it in another function that passes a querystring and loads the page into a modal popup, here is the function

```
case 'Change': {
        GetModal('GO_Update_Employee.aspx?id=newID&DoWhat=Update', 'Update Employee', 500, 500);
    } break;
```

So to double check to make sure that I am getting the querystring, I am stepping through the Page_Load event of the called page. This is how I am reading the querystring

```
string qsDoWhat = Request.QueryString["DoWhat"].ToString();
if (qsDoWhat == "Update")
{
    string myIDToUpdate = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
}
```

Well when I check to see the ID all I am getting is the variable name and not the actual value from the variable, and the value in the variable is 10012.

How do I get the actual value of the variable and not the name?

Comment: Because you are not concatenating your id into the address string, you just have a single string. Just because your varible's name is in the string doesnt mean it gets replaced with its value. You want: `aspx?id='+myID+'&DoWhat`

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I didn't even think of that. It did the trick. If you want to post it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Down votes because I forgot one simple thing? I guess no one forgets anything, must be nice to have an outstanding memory

Comment: @Chris It's a psycho community. Don't get offended, here is an up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newID` is a variable you defined in JavaScript so mentioning its name in a string will not cause its value to be used within that string.

Replace the JavaScript string `'GO_Update_Employee.aspx?id=newID&DoWhat=Update'` with `'GO_Update_Employee.aspx?id=' + newID + '&DoWhat=Update'`